# RichTextBox не воспринимает кириллицу

Tags: c#, winforms, rtf

Есть `RichTextBox`, в который грузится файл шаблона конечного документа через `richTextBox.LoadFile()`. В самом документе присутствует кириллица и отображается в самом контроле корректно, но когда я заменяю шаблоны типа `${width}` на любой русский текст в ответ вижу иероглифы и невнятные символы.

Сам `Rtf` выглядит так.

> \pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\tqc\tx826\tx852\'c7\'e0\'ea\'e0\'e7\'f7\'e8\'ea:
>   \lang1033\b\f3
>   ${owner}\line\lang1049\b0\f2\'d2\'e5\'eb\'e5\'f4\'ee\'ed
>   \'e7\'e0\'ea\'e0\'e7\'f7\'e8\'ea\'e0: \lang1033\b\f3
>   ${ownerPhone}\line\lang1049\b0\f2\'c4\'e0\'f2\'e0
>   \'ef\'f0\'e8\'b8\'ec\'e0: \lang1033\b\f3
>   ${inDate}\lang1049\f2\line\b0\'c4\'e0\'f2\'e0
>   \'e2\'fb\'e4\'e0\'f7\'e8:\lang1033\f3  \b $\

На юникод не похоже. Кто сталкивался подскажите как сконвертить строку из переменной в исправный фрагмент RTF документа. Кодировка самого файла ANSI

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
var bytes = enc.GetBytes(text);
var replacement = string.Concat(bytes.Select(b => string.Format(@"\'{0:x2}", b)));
```

Не уверен насчёт правильности константы 1251.

Comment: Спасибо за вариант, но все равно не работает. Пробовал все основные кодировки

Comment: @user3493623: А вы можете дать минимальный пример компилирующегося кода, чтобы можно было на нём попробовать воспроизвести проблему?